# Qt3D: Attempted to set unsupported sample count

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt3d

(Edit: see comments below: the problem is not related to the NetworkEntity or Network classes.)

I have a Qt3D C++ program that generates a subclass of `QEntity` which displays just fine inside a C++ `Qt3DWindow`. When I try to display the exact same `QEntity` from QML, I get a blank white window and thousands of the following error messages:

> Attempted to set unsupported sample count 3342452

> Resolve source (7405614) and destination (28) formats do not match

This the C++ code that displays the `NetworkEntity` just fine:

### main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    Network net;
    net.startAnimation();

    Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow view;
    view.defaultFrameGraph()->setClearColor(QColor(QRgb(0x00000000)));

    // Camera
    Qt3DRender::QCamera *camera = view.camera();
    camera->lens()->setPerspectiveProjection(45.0f, 16.0f/9.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    camera->setPosition(QVector3D(20.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    camera->setViewCenter(QVector3D(0, 0, 0));

    NetworkEntity *netEntity = new NetworkEntity();
    netEntity->setNet(&net);

    Qt3DExtras::QOrbitCameraController *camController = new Qt3DExtras::QOrbitCameraController(netEntity);
    camController->setLinearSpeed( 3.0f );
    camController->setLookSpeed( 40.0f );
    camController->setCamera(camera);

    view.setRootEntity(netEntity);
    view.show();
    
    return app.exec();
}
```

This is the QML version of the same which generates the errors:

### main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    Network net;
    net.startAnimation();

    QQuickView view;

    qmlRegisterType<NetworkEntity>("cv.network", 1, 0, "NetworkEntity");
    view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("_network", &net);
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/overlay.qml"));

    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

And the QML file that attempts to render the `NetworkEntity`:

### overlay.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import Qt3D.Core 2.15
import Qt3D.Render 2.15
import Qt3D.Extras 2.15
import Qt3D.Input 2.0
import QtQuick.Scene3D 2.5
import cv.network 1.0

Item {
    Scene3D {
        id: sceneRoot
        anchors.fill: parent
        cameraAspectRatioMode: Scene3D.AutomaticAspectRatio
        focus: true
        enabled: true

        Entity {
            Camera {
                id: camera
                projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
                fieldOfView: 45
                aspectRatio: 16 / 9
                nearPlane: 0.1
                farPlane: 100
                position: Qt.vector3d(20.0, 0, 0)
                upVector: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
                viewCenter: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
            }

            OrbitCameraController {
                id: cameraController
                camera: camera
                linearSpeed: 3
                lookSpeed: 40
            }

            components: [
                RenderSettings {
                    activeFrameGraph: ForwardRenderer {
                        clearColor: Qt.rgba(0, 0, 0.1, 1)
                        camera: camera
                        showDebugOverlay: false
                    }
                },
                InputSettings {}
            ]

            NetworkEntity {
                id: myEnt
                net: _network
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why does the QML version fail while the C++ version work perfectly? Should I be looking for particular things inside the C++ code that generates the `NetworkEntity`?

### networkentity.h

```
using namespace Qt3DCore;
using namespace Qt3DExtras;
using namespace Qt3DRender;

class NetworkEntity : public QEntity {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    NetworkEntity(QEntity *parentEntity = nullptr);
(...)
    Network *net() const;
    void setNet(Network *newNet);

signals:
    void netChanged();

private:
(...)
    Q_PROPERTY(Network *net READ net WRITE setNet NOTIFY netChanged)
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(NetworkEntity);
```

### network.h

```
#include <QObject>

class Network : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Network(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    Network(const Network &network);
    ~Network();

    void startAnimation();
    void stopAnimation();

    QList<Node *> allNodes() const;

    Timebase *getTimebase();
signals:
(...)
private:
(...)
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Network);
```

Comment: Unsure if `net: _network` really assigns the object of Network type to `NetworkEntity`. More source code needed for `NetworkEntity` and `Network` interface parts at least. `    view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("_network", &net);` implies that `net` should have object type either derived from `QObject` or  just `QVariant`. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlcontext.html#setContextProperty

Comment: Or you could have done it by creating entire new QML type derived from `NetworkEntity` but pre-setting all its nested data in C++ code rather than dragging it through the context.

Comment: Both NetworkEntity and Network classes are subclasses of QObject. Source of NetworkEntity added in original post.

Comment: Tried removing the NetworkEntity element altogether from the QML file and I'm getting the same error, so the problem is limited to the overlay.qml file minus the NetworkEntity element or the main file that instantiates it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overlay.qml file did not set any size to the parent `Item` of the Scene3D. Specifying a size or setting the `anchors.fill` property resolved the problem.

This file now works:

### overlay.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import Qt3D.Core 2.15
import Qt3D.Render 2.15
import Qt3D.Extras 2.15
import Qt3D.Input 2.0
import QtQuick.Scene3D 2.5
import cv.network 1.0

Item {
    anchors.fill: parent

    Scene3D {
        id: sceneRoot
        anchors.fill: parent
        cameraAspectRatioMode: Scene3D.AutomaticAspectRatio
        focus: true
        enabled: true

        Entity {
            Camera {
                id: camera
                projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
                fieldOfView: 45
                aspectRatio: 16 / 9
                nearPlane: 0.1
                farPlane: 100
                position: Qt.vector3d(20.0, 0, 0)
                upVector: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
                viewCenter: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
            }

            OrbitCameraController {
                id: cameraController
                camera: camera
                linearSpeed: 3
                lookSpeed: 40
            }

            components: [
                RenderSettings {
                    activeFrameGraph: ForwardRenderer {
                        clearColor: Qt.rgba(0, 0, 0.1, 1)
                        camera: camera
                        showDebugOverlay: false
                    }
                },
                InputSettings {}
            ]

            NetworkEntity {
                id: myEnt
                net: _network
            }
        }
    }
}
```